# Studying fixed point algebra under group action

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $M$ is in standard form, consider the action of a finite group on $M$, does the fixed point subalgebra under the action is in standard form? What we can say if $M$ is hyperfinite $\mathrm{II}_{1}$ factor?

Comment: No; if the action of a finite group $G$ is outer then you get a subfactor of index equal to the order of the group; denote the inclusion by $N \subset M$. It means that the dimension of $L^{2}(M)$ as an $N$-module is equal to $|G|$ and the dimension of the standard form is equal to $1$.